# jQuery Ajax POST request not hitting Spring controller

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I am unable to hit my spring controller using jQUERY AJAX POST.
I am trying to fetch a list of string using JSON response.

My javascript function which is called when a dropdown is selected:

```
function doAjaxPost() {  

  var name = $('#selected_report').val();

  alert("POST Ajax request initiating.... name : " + name);

  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/NewILR/interfaceReportsSearch/findEntityTypes", 
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({selectedReport:name}),  
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response){
      if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
          alert("SUCCESS");
      }else{
            alert("FAILURE");
      }       
    },  
    error: function(e){  
      alert('Error: ' + e);  
    }  
  });  
}
```

**NOTE** Two of the above alerts are displayed (POST Ajax request initiating... and 'Error: ' + e))

Spring Controller to handle the AJAX request:

```
@RequestMapping (value="/interfaceReportsSearch/findEntityTypes",method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody JsonResponse addUser(@RequestBody String selectedReport , BindingResult result ){

    System.out.println("Ajax Request Received! reportName = " + selectedReport);
```

**NOTE** the above print statement is never executed.
I also do not see a single console output, maybe the request does not get to the server.

No special beans are added to the servlet condiguration but I have the below two added:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Following jars are added to my classpath.

```
jackson-core-2.2.0
jackson-annotations-2.2.0
jackson-databind-2.2.0
```

**UPDATE**

Solved: changed the datatype to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your url attribute of ajax request by following:

```
url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/NewILR/interfaceReportsSearch/findEntityTypes",
```

This should do the job for you.

Comment: If i want to call from html means what i do ?

Comment: than you need to replace context path with your fully qualified domain name i.e http://yourdomain.co.in/NewILR/...